# Check if any of two columns exists in another one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got two columns in Table2 (T2) and one column in Table1 (T1). Example data

```
  Table2:  
    AccountNr OfferNr  
    123D       ITALY
    45C        Pronto  
    667        Belgium


  Table1  
Description  
"Account Number: 123D Offer Number ITALY"
"Account Number: 45C Offer Number"  
"Account Number: Offer Number Belgium"
```

As you can see, column Description from Table1 contains sometimes all two columns from Table2, sometimes only one.
I'm trying to list all rows from Table2 where there's no AccountNr or OfferNr in Description.
If there's at least one then I'm not listing it.

What I tried is:

```
select t2.AccountNr, t2.OfferNr
from Table2 t2
where not exists (select 1 Description
              from Table1 t1
              where t1.Description like ('%' + t2.AccountNr + '%') or  t1.Description like ('%' + t2.OfferNr + '%')
             )
```

But it seems to losing data, in example if I use only OfferNr in where clause in subquery I'm getting rows that aren't present in original query but should be.

Comment: "But it seems not quite good" is not a very good problem description. What is your actual output, and what is your desired output?

Comment: What does "it seems not quite good" mean? For the provided data, your query shouldn't return anything. Are you getting an error?

Comment: No, I'm missing some data, for example when I only use "OfferNr" in where clause in subquery I'm getting rows that aren't present in original query but should be as there's no such row in Description field.

Comment: Why don't you update your question and explain what you have, what you are getting, and what you want? That way, you aren't wasting anyone's time.

Comment: Allright I've updated but there's nothing more to add. My desired output is in my question:   
" I'm trying to list all rows from Table2 where there's no AccountNr or OfferNr in Description. If there's at least one then I'm not listing it."

Comment: Cool - then my original observation answers your question: For the provided data, your query shouldn't return anything.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: @PeterAbolins well but it's returning.

Comment: I will try again... If it is returning something, then include that something in your question, so that we can all see what you are getting, and can help you fix it so that you get what you are expecting instead. Basically, you should provide the following information: Input -> Process Code -> Output; Expected Output / Errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all records from `Table1` which have neither an **AccountNr** nor an **OfferNr** in `Table2`, then the following will work. *This is, by the way, identical to what you had!*

```
SELECT 
    t2.AccountNr, t2.OfferNr
FROM 
    Table2 t2
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT Description 
        FROM Table1 t1
        WHERE 
          t1.Description LIKE ('%' + t2.AccountNr + '%') OR  
          t1.Description LIKE ('%' + t2.OfferNr + '%')
)
```

However, If you instead want all records from `Table1` which have an **AccountNr**, or an **OfferNr**, or **both**, in `Table2`, then the following will work.

```
SELECT 
    t2.AccountNr, t2.OfferNr
FROM 
    Table2 t2
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT Description 
        FROM Table1 t1
        WHERE 
          t1.Description LIKE ('%' + t2.AccountNr + '%') OR  
          t1.Description LIKE ('%' + t2.OfferNr + '%')
)
```